# Python, can't assign to function call. I've trying to fix it for day, with no success

Tags: python

```
def consequence_0 ():
    consequence_0 () = input ("Now you can see into darker places...")
    try:
        if consequence_0 == 'shiny object':
            print ("You picked up a key")
        elif consequence_0 == 'pick up shiny object':
            print ("You picked up a key")
    except ValueError:
        print ("You can't carry out that action")
        print

def consequence_1 ():
    consequence_1 () = input ()
    try:
        if consequence_1 == 'open bible':
            print ("The bible opens and you see a single page attached to the inside of the cover")
        elif consequence_1 == 'open the bible':
            print ("The bible opens and you see a single page attached to the inside of the cover")
    except ValueError:
        print ("You can't carry out that action")
        print
```

Comment: Can you please post the stack trace? ... however, `consequence_0 () = input` is a function call and you are trying to assign to it. What did you want to achieve?

Comment: What exactly do you think `()` does? You might want to seek seek out a tutorial.

Comment: A naming suggestion:  There's no reason to name your local variables after the function they're in, and especially no reason the name for whatever-the-user-typed should know that it's in the _n_-th function that handles user input.  Name things for what they _are_... bearing in mind that `input` (frustratingly both a noun and a verb) is already claimed by a built-in.  Consider something like `user_input`, `players_move`, or even just `action`.  Both functions can safely use the same name for the same role, since separate functions use separate namespaces.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't assign to function call (PYTHON)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28652444/cant-assign-to-function-call-python)

Comment: You're defining some functions, and the first thing you try to do is call them recursively, then attempt to assign to the result?  That makes absolutely no sense.  (1) Pick a new name for your variable (2) Assign to the variable without trying to call it like a function.  E.g. change `consequence_0() = ...` to `my_var = ...`

Answer (score 1):

Change:`consequence_0 () = input ("Now you can see into darker places...")`

to this: `consequence_0 = input ("Now you can see into darker places...")`

And also this
`consequence_1 () = input ()` to `consequence_1 = input ()`

In this code you're trying to assign the result of `input` to the function, that doesn't work. You want to assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Python shows you the line that has the error. Its likely

```
consequence_0 () = input ("Now you can see into darker places...")
```

which is a function call and you can't assign to a function call. Remove the cowboy legs and you'll have a function that prompts for darker places

```
def consequence_0 ():
    consequence_0 = input ("Now you can see into darker places...")
    try:
        if consequence_0 == 'shiny object':
            print ("You picked up a key")
        elif consequence_0 == 'pick up shiny object':
            print ("You picked up a key")
    except ValueError:
        print ("You can't carry out that action")
        print
```